# Computing the derivative of a linear map

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the space $C\bigl([a,b];\mathbb{R}\bigr)$ equipped with the $\sup$ norm. Define the operator $$\mathfrak{f} :  C\bigl([a,b];\mathbb{R}\bigr) \to C\bigl([a,b];\mathbb{R}\bigr) \: \text{by} \ \ \mathfrak{f}(\varphi)(t) = \int_{a}^{b}(\varphi(s))^{3} ds \cdot \varphi(t), \ \ \text{for} \ \varphi\in C\bigl([a,b];\mathbb{R}\bigr)$$

- Now for a given $\chi\in C\bigl([a,b];\mathbb{R}\bigr)$,I want to find a linear operator $\mathscr{L} : C\bigl([a,b];\mathbb{R}\bigr) \to C\bigl([a,b];\mathbb{R}\bigr)$ satisfying $$\lim_{||\varphi||_{\infty}\to 0} \:  \frac{\mathfrak{f}(\chi+\psi)-\mathfrak{f}(\chi)-\mathscr{L}\varphi}{||\varphi||_{\infty}}=0.$$
- I also want to show $\mathscr{L}$ is continuous. I know that it suffices to show  $\mathscr{L}$ is bounded.
- Also I want to calculate the derivative of $D\mathfrak{f}(\chi)$ of $\mathfrak{f}$ at $\chi$ $?$

A solution would be of great help.

Comment: First, we should denote $(\mathfrak f(\varphi))(t)$, since $\varphi(t)$ is a real number, and $\mathfrak f$ acts on functions, not numbers. I think you mean "$\mathcal L$ is continuous" not $\chi$.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Thanks, is it ok now.

Comment: There still is a typo in the second item in the list ($\mathcal L$ instead of $\chi$), and the map $\mathfrak f$ is not linear (so the title needs an edit).

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: Thanks.

Comment: Expand $(\varphi+h)^3$, and multiplying by $\varphi+h$, we can remove terms in $h^j$, $j\geqslant 2$. What is the linear part in $h$?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: I am sorry I dont get it. why are you doing $(\varphi+h)^{3}$. I guess you are calculating $\mathfrak{f}(\varphi +h)(t)$, but why are you doing that.

Comment: I am an Amateur here. Learning on my own. Thats why I asked for a solution. I apologize.

Comment: There is a typo in the difference quotient. It should be $\varphi$ instead of $\psi$ (I guess!).

Answer (score 1):

You can proceed as follows: Consider the difference quotient
$$\frac{\mathfrak{f}(\chi + \epsilon\phi) - \mathfrak{f}(\chi)}{\epsilon}$$
and then pass to the limit $\epsilon\to 0$. You should observe that the result will be linear in $\phi$ and call the corresponding linear operator $\mathcal{L}$. In your case, Davide already told you what to do (this goes through without complications).

For your last bullet: What you did was calculating the Gateaux-derivative of $\mathfrak{f}$ (there are several other notions of derivatives around, so you should be more precise in what kind of derivative you want).

Comment: Could you please elaborate more.